# Remove the login that appears at the bottom of a registration profile

Tags: civimember, profile

I have a profile for a visitor to use that allows them to purchase a membership and at the same time creating a drupal account. All works well, except there is a login block at the bottom of the page that I want to eliminate because it is moot and the user will receive a one-time login from drupal.

Why is the login on the profile page, and how can I get rid of it??

Carl

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's the Drupal login block - so to not show that on your civicrm pages - get into your blocks configuration and in the visibility settings make it such that it does not display on civicm/* (or make that less generic if you like).

Comment: KarinG, Thanks ... duh.  That's what I thought it was, but the login block was not being used for the site, it was custom ..., BUT I overlooked the fact that I was using the 'seven' theme for CiviCRM and not the custom theme that the rest of the site uses.  Hence, low and behold, the login block was in the content region of the Seven theme.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is: It was a login block and not a login that mysteriously was created by the profile.

If one uses a different theme for the civicrm section of their website and finding ~rogue~ blocks ... remember that its a civicrm theme and not the default website theme.  Simple fix and easily overlooked.  Kudos for KarinG!